# How to append more than one element using appendChild

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have one cell (columns), in which I want to add two buttons. This is what I created:

```
var editbtn = document.createElement('button');
editbtn.type= "button";
editbtn.className= "editbtn";
editbtn.id= "edit-button-"+(i+1);
editbtn.innerHTML= "Edit";
editbtn.onclick = editRow.bind(this, i + 1); 

var savebtn = document.createElement('button');      
savebtn.type= "button";
savebtn.className= "savebtn";
savebtn.id= "save-button-"+(i+1);
savebtn.innerHTML= "Save";
savebtn.onclick = saveRow.bind(this, i + 1);

cell3.appendChild(editbtn); 
cell3.appendChild(savebtn);
```

However, only the `savebtn` appears. How to append two buttons or more in the same column?

Comment: you are editing `editbtn` twice.

Comment: Thanks. It was a typo.

Comment: Your code is hard to test, as `i is undefined`, `saveRow is undefined`, `cell3 is undefined`, etc. What does your console say? Any error?

Comment: There's no visibility on `cell3`, so I imagine the issue is there or something else (like a JS error); however, the simplest reduced test case shows it works: https://jsfiddle.net/phn0tL9v/

Comment: Here's it working (ignoring the `onclick`s): https://jsfiddle.net/phn0tL9v/1/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can easily do that with an array and a for loop:

```
var names = ['edit', 'save'];
var editRows = [editRow, saveRow];

for ( var i = 0; i < names.length; i++ )
{
    var btn       = document.createElement('button');
    btn.type      = "button";
    btn.className = names[i] + "btn";
    btn.id        = names[i] + "-button-" + (i+1);
    btn.innerHTML = names[i];
    btn.onclick   = editRows[i].(this, i + 1);

    cell3.appendChild( editbtn );
}
```

You can add as many button as you want then just updating `names` and `editRows` accordingly, no need to touch the `for` loop.

Comment: What do you mean?